# Short connection with Lufthansa Flight

Tags: layovers, short-connections, muc

Intend to book flight depart from Geneva arrive in Kuala Lumpur.
The first flight from Geneva to Munich is Lufthansa flight #2389 with short layover of 40 minutes before connection of next Lufthansa flight #790 to head for Singapore for final destination to Kuala Lumpur.

Is this time enough to catch the next connecting flight with same airlines? The bag with check direct to

Comment: Is 40 minutes enough to catch the next connecting flight with same airlines. The bag with check direct to

Comment: If you book a single ticket, the airline will take responsibility for a missed connection (rebooking, accommodation, meals, etc within limits).

Comment: Personally, I consider it way too short, because delays happens, and in this case the plan B is (I think) very bad. In other words, in case of delay, you risk to be put on the next day intercontinental flight. (you will get food, hotel, but you arrive one day later). I also try to avoid too short connection if you have baggage (and if you go on holidays): risk to have delayed baggage increases. For destinations with many alternate flights, the minimum connecting time is often good.

Answer (score 6):

Lufthansa has a [PDF file](https://www.lufthansa.com/mediapool/pdf/63/media_373363.pdf) which answers this question:

> **Is the Minimum Connecting Time of 30 minutes
>   really enough for changing the aircraft?**
>
> The answer is a clear yes. Although this short changing time is unique in Europe,
>   we nevertheless have an exemplary punctuality rate, which is a very important
>   fact especially for our business travelers [...]

Answer (score 1):

The same answer as usual, with all flights on the same ticket:

- the airline thinks you can make it, otherwise they wouldn’t sell the connection
- good airlines will make efforts to make sure you do, especially if the incoming flight is slightly late: they will probably have someone waiting for you at the gate when you disembark to escort you to the next flight. In this situation (short-haul -> long-haul), they will probably hold the plane for a bit if necessary.
- be prepared to walk fast
- try to get a seat as close as possible to the front of the plane
- notify the crew on board
- check out terminal maps beforehand, and know which gates are likely
- it’s the airline’s responsibility to get you to your destination (rebooking you on the next available flight) and take care of you if there are delays (hotels, meals, and the absolutely essential telex messages)
- but if you don’t make it, the next flight may be the next day. Be prepared for that.
- you may make the connection, but not your luggage, which may arrive a few days later. Be prepared for that.

If the flights are not on the same ticket, forget about it.